# Скользящее среднее по сгруппированным данным

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[f'name_{i}' for i in range(0,12)],
                          [f'par_{i%3}' for i in range(0,12)]], index=['names', 'parameters']).transpose() 
df['x'] = df.groupby(['parameters']).cumcount() + 1
```

Колонка 'names' упорядочена, 'parameters' -- нет, 'x' -- любые числа.

Как для каждого 'names' по совпадающим 'parameters' посчитать среднее двух (n) последних значений 'x'?  Как-то с помощью groupby, rolling, но не могу сообразить, как это сделать, помогите, пожалуйста. Первые два (n) значений будут, соответственно, nan.

Comment: что значит `"посчитать среднее двух (n) последних значений 'x'"`? Можете привести в вопросе ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос оформлен крайне небрежно. В вашем примере значение 'names' - уникальны в датафрейме. Как можно "для каждого 'names' ..... посчитать среднее двух (n) последних значений 'x" даже сгрупировав их по 'parameters'?  Еще раз "посчитать среднее для уникальных (не повторяющихся по датафрему) значениях параметра 'names'??? Про то, причем тут *скользящее* среднее -  я вообще боюсь спрашивать.

Если отбросить эту некорректность условия и трактовать ее как *"сгрупировать по 'parameters', найти в каждой группе 2 (или n) последних значений и посчитать их среднее (внутри группы)"*, то сделать это можно так:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[f'name_{i}' for i in range(0,12)],
                          [f'par_{i%3}' for i in range(0,12)]], index=['names', 'parameters']).transpose()
df['x'] = df.groupby(['parameters']).cumcount() + 1
df.groupby(['parameters']).tail([2]).groupby(['parameters']).mean()
```

Результат -

```
Out[30]: 
              x
parameters     
par_0       3.5
par_1       3.5
par_2       3.5
```

Ну а под корректную формулировку условий задачи теперь тюнингуйте этот пример самостоятельно.